# Measuring Activity start time using method tracing inaccurate?

Tags: android, optimization, android-traceview

My activity (that uses camera) starts quite slowly, according to Logcat:

```
08-21 21:51:56.672: I/ActivityManager(488): Displayed com.blabla/.activities.TakePhotoActivity: +1s472ms
```

So I decided to use method profiling to see where the problem is (this is where the slow Activity is started):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Debug.startMethodTracing();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TakePhotoActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
}
```

and in onResume in TakePhotoActivity I call:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    cameraView.onResume();
    Debug.stopMethodTracing();
}
```

But, to my surprise, Traceview shows only 260ms of method calls, so I'm losing over 1 second somewhere!

How do I find out what is happening during this time?

Comment: This certainly comes from the call to `Camera.open()`. To be sure, take a systrace trace from DDMS

Comment: I guess Debug.startMethodTracing("Sample") and Debug.stopMethodTracing() takes some time, so that ActivityManager is displaying you more seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710674/Using-Android-Traceview-in-Eclipse) is a good tutorial about how to use trace view on Android application.Just run it and check which all sub methods are causing the time lose.It has a nice visual representation of time usage.